# How to make a part of an HTML file follow a specific css stylesheet

Tags: html, css

So I have looked for a while but i can't find the answer. To explain more precisely, I have an HTML file where there are `<style>` tags in the head of the file. I want for the header of the HTML file to folow a dedicated CSS file. Right now the tags in the head override the CSS file.

Comment: Please post your HTML code and CSS file to make it easier to understand your problem.

Comment: CSS is applied through a specific set of programmatic rules. Priority, Top-down and specificity.  Anything written in `<style>` takes priority over a style sheet, in-line takes priority over `<style>` other than that, it comes down to specificity and top-down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is applied through a specific set of programmatic rules.

1. in-line CSS. This has highest priority and overrides both stylesheets and `<style>` tag rules.
2. `<style>` tag has second highest priority and overrides stylesheets.
3. Stylesheet has the lowest priority and will only come into effect if the 2 prior cases aren't available.

Outside of those 3 points, another set of rules also apply. Specificity, and top-down. The most specified rules take precedence, and afterwards it's whichever rule was specified last.

In action:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  .btn-danger {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 5px solid black;
  }
</style>
<button class="btn btn-danger" style="background-color: green;">CSS TESTER</button>
```

What you experience in the above snippet, is that we pull in a Bootstrap stylesheet, and style our button with the `btn-danger` class to give it a red background and subtle border with red color.

We then add a `<style>` tag, make the button blue and change the border styling.

Lastly, we make an in-line style rule to make the button green, making the end-result a button with a green background color, and a big black border, overriding the Bootstrap class from the stylesheet.

Find a quick read on the problem you are experiencing [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Rules-to-override-Style-Sheet-Rule-in-CSS).